# Laravel Unable to guess the MIME type when extension=php_fileinfo.dll is enabled?

Tags: php, laravel

I am running into the following error when trying to use the Laravel Excel package to force download of a file `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` is enabled (not commented out). Where would I go from here in troubleshooting such error?

Comment: Which "following error"?

Comment: `Unable to find MIME type` is the error

Comment: The content of the file is not identifiable by fileinfo extension as a known mime type. It's probably a malformed or corrupted file. But without any code example it's only a guess.